# Swift Delegate through CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have big `UICollectionViewCells`, inside I have another (small) `UICollectionViewController`, so it basically cells that have multiple cells.

The questions is, how do I notify/update my main `UICollectionViewController`(that has big cells) that something changed in my small `UICollectionViewControllers`

Basically, I configure cells in `cellForItemAt` in big `UICollectionViewController`, its cell has a property with `didSet` and there I configure small `UICollectionViewController`

So basically, this is Trello-ish app.
Here is my ListsViewController (that has lists)

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ListCollectionViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! ListCollectionViewCell
        let list = lists[indexPath.row]
        cell.listName.text = "     \(list.name)"
        cell.listId = list.id
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.cards = cards[list.id]
        cell.cardsController.collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
```

and  inside my `ListCollectionViewCell`:

```
lazy var cardsController = CardsCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
var delegate: CardsCollectionViewControllerDelegate?
var cards: [String]? = [] {
        didSet {
            addSubview(cardsController.view)
            // constraints here
            cardsController.cards = cards ?? []
            cardsController.listId = listId
            cardsController.delegate = delegate
        }
    }
```

Then, inside CardsCollectionViewController I have a method  `didSelectItemAt` where the very last card acts like a button `"Add new Card"`.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add card", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addTextField()

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: .cancel, handler: { [] (_) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
                let textField = alert?.textFields![0]
                let cardName = textField?.text

                NetworkManager.shared.createCardWith(name: cardName ?? "", onList: self.listId, completion: {
                    self.delegate?.didAddCard()
                })

            }))
        }

    }


protocol CardsCollectionViewControllerDelegate {
    func didAddCard()
}


    extension ListsViewController: CardsCollectionViewControllerDelegate {
        func didAddCard() {
            self.getDataFromTrello()
        }
    }
```

All API Network stuff works correctly and cards can be added to the trello itself, now the final part is: when I click "OK" on the alert, I need to call `getDataFromTrello()` method which is a method of `ListsViewController` (first) and I'm not really sure how do I do that.

Comment: @Sammy I do have that, I understand how it can be implemented for example, when you click "add new text", new ViewController pops up, you input text there and pass text through delegate to the first ViewController. The problem is that in this situation, it has to be done through BigViewController -> Cell -> SmallViewController. I'm either stupid or this is slightly different

Comment: @Sammy I did, hope it can be useful.

Comment: @Sammy Edited. That's what I tried and it kinda worked, but my whole collectionView gets messed up, some cards are duplicated, they go to wrong lists and stuff.

Comment: @Sammy The issue is fixed. I just had to empty all arrays in getDataFromTrello()